# GROUP BY not working in my code

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the avg difference between order requested delivery date and actual delivery date, by Destination. The below is giving me issues. Do you know where I am going wrong? The message I am getting is "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least on column that is not an outer reference"

```
SELECT CONCAT(Locations.City, ', ', Locations.State) AS Destination,
       AVG(DATEDIFF("Day", Orders.ReqDate, Orders.SchedDate)) AS "Average Diff"
FROM dbo.Orders,
     dbo.Locations
WHERE dbo.Orders.OrderNum= dbo.Locations.OrderNum
GROUP BY 'Destination'
```

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to improve your query.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT CONCAT(l.City, ', ', l.State) AS Destination,
       AVG(DATEDIFF(Day, o.ReqDate, o.SchedDate)*1.0) AS "Average Diff"
FROM dbo.Orders o join
     dbo.Locations l
     ON o.OrderNum = l.OrderNum
GROUP BY CONCAT(l.City, ', ', l.State) ;
```

Note the following:

- `"Day"` --> `Day`.  `Day` is a keyword in SQL Server and does not need quotes.
- The use of table aliases, `o` and `l` to make the query more readable.
- The multiplication by `1.0`.  `DATEDIFF()` returns an integer.  The average of an integer (in SQL Server) is an integer.  Usually, you would want a decimal number.  You can also convert this to `float` or to another format, but I find `*1.0` to be the simplest way for a fast conversion.
- Fixed the `GROUP BY` (as noted in other answers).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT CONCAT(Locations.City, ', ', Locations.State) AS Destination,
       AVG(DATEDIFF("Day", Orders.ReqDate, Orders.SchedDate)) AS "Average Diff"
FROM dbo.Orders,
     dbo.Locations
WHERE dbo.Orders.OrderNum= dbo.Locations.OrderNum
GROUP BY CONCAT(Locations.City, ', ', Locations.State)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to group using a string value `'Destination'`, try changing it to use the expression `CONCAT(Locations.City, ', ', Locations.State)` and it should work:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Locations.City, ', ', Locations.State) AS Destination,
       AVG(DATEDIFF("Day", Orders.ReqDate, Orders.SchedDate)) AS "Average Diff"
FROM dbo.Orders,
     dbo.Locations
WHERE dbo.Orders.OrderNum= dbo.Locations.OrderNum
GROUP BY CONCAT(Locations.City, ', ', Locations.State)
```